Python, pandas Dataframe row
I am trying to iterate through each row of a Dataframe. However, using row on Column B (a comma separated field) is splitting this into single characters.



Column A
Column B




pet.
dog,cat



The code I’m using:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    A1 = row['Column A']
    A2 = row['Column B']
    print(A2)
    A3 = add_units['Column A'].str.split(',').tolist()
    A4 = list(A3)
    A5 = json.dumps(A4)
    print(A5)

I have tried list and json dumps and the format looks correct after the print.But then I can’t iterate and get the error list index out of range.

import pandas as pd
import json

# Example DataFrame
data = {'Column A': ['pet', 'animal'], 'Column B': ['dog,cat', 'bird,fish']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Iterating through each row
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    A1 = row['Column A']
    A2 = row['Column B']
    
    # Splitting the comma-separated values in Column B
    A3 = A2.split(',')  # Directly split the row's value of Column B
    A5 = json.dumps(A3)
    print(A5)
    
    # Example of processing each item in A3
    for item in A3:
        print(f"Processing {item} in context of {A1}")


Where this is processing each item, is it handling each row as the same item? For example, dog and cat processed in the same iteration.

I may not understand your needs. Can you provide some expected output?
